# Swapping values from database in datagridview /w dataset

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, datagridview

I have a question regarding the swapping of a few values in my database table.

What I am about to build is a website that displays a survey (in ASP.net). The questions will be stored in a table called `SURVEY_QUESTIONS` (in SQL Server).

The table has the following columns:

- survey_question_id (int)
- question (string)
- type (string)
- active (bool)
- order (int)

Now, a question will be stored in the question column, for example:

> Are you satisfied with the current conditions?

The type will be either a multiple choice or a open column. Active means that if its active, only then the question will be displayed in the survey. The problem that I have is the last column, the `order`. I want to order the questions from lowest to highest. So if I have 5 questions, they will be nicely ordered according to the order column, 1,2,3,4,5.

I have a C# (Winforms) application where I add questions and edit them. I do this in a datagridview and I used a dataset to fill the grid view. When I, for example press the save button, the changes in the datagridview will be updated to my database.

Now let's say that question one has order number 3 and question five has order number 1. I want question one to be the first one displayed, meaning its order number should be 1. But in this case, question five already has that order number, what I want is whenever a "occupied" order number is assigned to another question, their order numbers swap.

I have the following code behind the save button to update to the database:

```
DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure want to edit a question?", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    this.SURVEY_QUESTIONTableAdapter.Update(_PVB1314_005DataSet.SURVEY_QUESTION);
    datagridviewTest.Refresh();
    MessageBox.Show("Database updated");
}
```

I hope someone can help me out on this one, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start using Stored Procedures. In your code you have a Message box showing 'Database Updated'. How do you KNOW the database has been updated? You haven't even got the code in a try catch block.

Write a stored procedure with input parameters of the QuestionID you want to update and the OrderID you want to update it to. You can then easily test if the OrderID you want is already in use and, if not, run an update statement.

If it is in use, and your order column does not allow duplicated values, you might have to temporarily assign the row whose OrderID you want to take with a temporary value, maybe -1, store the current OrderID of the row you want to change in a variable, update the row whose OrderID you want to change with the correct OrderID and then Update the row whose OrderID you have just changed to -1 using the OrderID you have stored temporarily.